# AUTH_REQUIRED with Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two states in my application -- /auth and /masters. the latter is the state where i wld like to direct the user only once he or she has been authenticated.

So, i understand that we can use '$urlRouterProvider.otherwise' to configure a default state in the application to /auth. So the foll is my code:

```
angular.module('ngClassifieds', ['ngMaterial', 'ui.router', 'firebase'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $mdThemingProvider
        .theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('blue-grey')
        .accentPalette('orange');


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/auth');

     $stateProvider
        .state('auth', {
          url: '/auth',
          templateUrl: 'components/auth/auth.tpl.html',
          controller: 'authCtrl'
        })

    $stateProvider
        .state('masters', {
            url: '/masters',
            templateUrl: 'components/classifieds.tpl.html',
            controller: 'classifiedsCtrl' 

        });
});
```

Now, if i enter, for example, anything other than /masters, i am directed to /auth; however, if i enter /masters, i am not directed to /auth.

i was made to understand that i need to look for AUTH_REQUIRED error in Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html) in order to achieve the desired result. However, i feel i'm punching above my weight in trying to incorporate the functionality. So i'd appreciate if you can provide me some guidane. This is how i have tried to refactor the above code, but it's a mess:

```
angular.module('ngClassifieds', ['ngMaterial', 'ui.router', 'firebase'])


.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
  // and redirect the user back to the home page
  if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
    $state.go("auth");
  }
});
}]);




.config(function($mdThemingProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $mdThemingProvider
        .theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('blue-grey')
        .accentPalette('orange');


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/auth');

     $stateProvider
        .state('auth', {
          url: '/auth',
          templateUrl: 'components/auth/auth.tpl.html',
          controller: 'authCtrl',
          resolve: {
              // controller will not be loaded until $waitForAuth resolves
              // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
              "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                // $waitForAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
                return Auth.$waitForAuth();
              }]
            }
        })

    $stateProvider
        .state('masters', {
            url: '/masters',
            templateUrl: 'components/classifieds.tpl.html',
            controller: 'classifiedsCtrl',
            resolve: {
              // controller will not be loaded until $requireAuth resolves
              // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
              "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
                // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
                return Auth.$requireAuth();
              }]
            }


        });
});
```

Comment: You have included code that uses AngularFire, but have not included the library itself. Start on the first page of this guide: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/

Comment: Frank, i have included the library `<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
 <!-- AngularFire -->
 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Follow the guide from start to finish. It contains more than just a script include. There's also an entire page about injecting and using `$firebaseAuth`.